# Why is body in a mailtolink not included by android's E-Mail application?

Tags: android, html

I have this simple code line in a webpage.

```
<a href="mailto:em@ail.com?body=https://url.com/picture.jpg">Send</a>
```

When I open this in android (webview) my email-client opens + the email is being put there, yet the body remains empty.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Your body should be url encoded

    `URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");`

Your link should be something like this
`<a href="mailto:em@ail.com?body=https%3A%2F%2Furl.com%2Fpicture.jpg">Send</a>`

Comment: Also, there is no requirement for all email apps to look for URL parameters to pre-fill in things other than the destination email address. If your `body` parameter winds up working for some email apps, that is wonderful, but do not assume that *all* email apps will use your supplied `body`.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I make it work with https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhxGw.png ?

Comment: Um, well, that icon could point to any number of apps. I have no particular instructions for any email app. My point is that you should not be relying upon it working, and if your plans require it to work all the time, you need new plans.

Comment: @CommonsWare It should only work for me. It is a private website. Also it is the standard eMail-Client installed on any android.